# miles display in distance slider falling down

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design, firefox

On http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/ the XX miles text is on it's own line compared to `distance (use slider)`, making it hidden behind the drag bar for the distance:

> [image]

After playing around a bit with Firebug, it seems like this is the villian:

```
.searchfields div.distance {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Feel free to check it out. Would be convinient to see that value :)

I get this result on Firefox 21.

Comment: Non repro on Chrome and IE10 so probably Firefox only bug, added proper tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now.

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Nice! Related issue which is cross browser: when selecting "Work remotely" the textbox and slider appear to get disabled, the textbox is indeed disabled but you can still use the slider.

Comment: Excellent and fast fix. Thanks!

Comment: @Robin: No prob.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Crazy Punyon's House of Bug Fixes: Buy One Get One FREE!

Comment: Awesome, also fixed third one that went unnoticed where the slider was enabled initially where it shouldn't. Poor bugs. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Word.